# Read JSON Data from an incoming Django Request and Displaying the Data to HTML

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm a month old of using Django and I want to create a Registration Form where the data will came from a POST Request (from a microreader that will throw a JSON data going to the Django View Endpoint). Once I received the response, I need to get the data_id and the user must input the name and its department, and displaying it as a form in the HTML that will be pushed to my database, once submitted. However, I'm having a hard time crafting this thing in views.py and its template.

This is the thrown JSON Response: {"station":"XXXXXXXX","type":"TYPE-XXX","data_id":"9198491920"}

This is the **views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def registration_form(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Process the JSON data
        json_data = json.loads(request.body)
        dataid = json_data.get('data_id')

        # Initialize the form with the received dataid
        form = RegistrationForm(initial={'data_id': dataid)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            department = form.cleaned_data['department']

            return render(request,'registration.html',{'form':form})
    else:
        # If GET request, initialize form
        form = RegistrationForm()
        
        return render(request, 'registration.html', {'form': form})
```

This is my **registration.html**. Although, you may not expect some things in my HTML since I'm trying all forms of displaying but there's no success.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block content %}

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

This is my **forms.py** for RegistrationForm.

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    dataid = forms.CharField(label='Data ID', max_length=100)
    name = forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=100)
    department = forms.CharField(label='Department', max_length=100)
```

I'm not sure where am I missing with since forms is returning some values from JSON but I cannot display the **data_id** value in the HTML. Hope you can help. Thanks!

Comment: **Typo**: In your form you are passing `'data_id': dataid` as the initial value while the field in your form is actually named `dataid`. Notice the underscore vs no underscore.

Answer (score 0):

So what you are doing is that,
At first, you are receiving a POST request, which is a `data-id`.
so after you initialized the form with data, you are checking if the form is valid.
The user didn't submit the form so the form will be invalid, so `form.is_valid` will return False.

you can add a `<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="get-dataid">` to differentiate between two POST requests.

```py
@csrf_exempt
def registration_form(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST.get("mode") == "get-dataid":
            # Process the JSON data
            json_data = json.loads(request.body)
            dataid = json_data.get('data_id')

            # Initialize the form with the received dataid
            form = RegistrationForm(initial={'data_id': dataid})
        else:
            # If form is not submitted, it will be invalid
            form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
            
            if form.is_valid():
                name = form.cleaned_data['name']
                department = form.cleaned_data['department']

        return render(request, 'registration.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        # If GET request, initialize form
        form = RegistrationForm()
        
        return render(request, 'registration.html', {'form': form})
```